# PHP literally outputting the word 'Array' instead of the values in said array

Tags: php, arrays

Before you immediately close the question, please read first. I know about var_dump(), print_r(), echo etc. It just doesn't seem to work in my particular use-case, or I'm unsure how exactly to implement them in my exact situation.

After updating to the integrated PDO data abstraction layer, its giving us our data back formatted a bit differently.

One of our forms would output a list of arrays converted to strings. Below is a snippet:

```
$this->output .= "<option id='".$option_name."' value='".$values[$i]."'".$selected.">".$options[$i]."</option>\n";
```

Each `$options[$i]` is an array that contained material id and description. So it would look something like this when output properly:

- Red Material 1234
- Blue Material 2235
- Green Material 3236
- ....etc...

What the array looks like for each would be: `Array ([description] => Red Material [materialid] => 1234)`

Now it just outputs:

- Array
- Array
- Array...

How can I just convert `$options[$i]` to a string before feeding it to this output field?

Some assistance would be appreciated. I feel like I'm getting caught up on something that should be trivial.

Comment: `$options[$i]["description"]`?

Answer (score 1):

`$options[$i]` is an array, and when you convert an array to a string you get the string `Array`.

You want to get the elements of the array:

```
$this->output .= "<option id='{$option_name}' value='{$values[$i]}' $selected>{$options[$i]['description']} {$options[$i]['materialid']}</option>\n";
```

Using string substitution instead of concatenation makes the code easier to read, and often avoids quoting problems.

Comment: Despite my question probably being trivial and easy (hence the usual downvotes), I still think this was extremely helpful, and did solve my issue. You also helped me format some old code to be MUCH easier to read. Barmar, this site needs more people like you. 
I suppose I have a follow up question. Is there a reason why my arrays were being handled differently after I changed my database extraction layer? Was my old class perhaps preprocessing the array before I was trying to display it?

Comment: Without seeing the old code I can't really say for sure. Maybe it was returning objects and the class has a `__toString()` method that produces the desired result.